# How to pass values of a parameter array as Item Datas in LR

Tags: loadrunner

I'm enhancing a Vuser Script in loadrunner 12.60, and as I mentioned in the question's title, I need to pass a group of item data to a form. These data are hidden so their values do not appear in the Data Items returned to the server in the recorded script. Now, I've extracted said values with a web_reg_save_param_ex, but the hidden inputs and their values are random, so maybe in one iteration I catch 5 elements and In another one I could catch more than 50.

I've made this section to know how many items are caught in the current iteration, it prints the name of the value and the value itself.

```
    nameCnt = atoi(lr_eval_string("{nomf_count}"));
    valCnt = atoi(lr_eval_string("{valf_count}"));

    lr_output_message("Number of vars found = %d",nameCnt);
    lr_output_message("Number of values found = %d",valCnt);

    for (y = 1; y <= nameCnt; y++) {
        sprintf(chainNom, "{nomf_%d}", y);
        lr_output_message ("%s: %s", cadenaNom, lr_eval_string(cadenaNom)); 
        sprintf(chainVal, "{valf_%d}", y);
        lr_output_message ("%s: %s", cadenaVal, lr_eval_string(cadenaVal));
    }
```

I have the name and the values extracted, but I don't know how to pass them as Data Items in the web_submit_form

Any help or even a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use web_custom_request() and build your own name|value pair structure

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other comment, add the ITEMDATA under your custom/submit request:

```
 ITEMDATA,
        "Name=<Your Parameter Name>", "Value={your_param_value}", ENDITEM,
        [...]
        LAST;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try lr_param_sprintf() function instead of sprintf().
This will save your value into a Loadrunner parameter rather than a c parameter. This you can directly pass to your web_submit_form

```
lr_param_sprintf ("chainNom", "{nomf_%d}", y);
lr_param_sprintf (chainVal, "{valf_%d}", y);
....
ITEMDATA,
"Name={chainNom}", "Value={chainVal}", ENDITEM,
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I didn't know about lr_param_sprintf, I'm dealing with UFT now but when I can I'll give it a try. In the submit form, there's no need to do a for or a while loop to insert the parameters?